# "slash before every quote" problem

Tags: php, mysql, html, security

I have a php page which contains a form.

Sometimes this page is submitted to itself (like when pics are uploaded).

I wouldn't want users to have to fill in every field again and again, so I use this as a value of a text-input inside the form:

```
value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_POST['annonsera_headline'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');?>">
```

This works, except it adds a "\" sign before every double-quote...

For instance writing 19" wheels gives after page is submitted to itself:

```
  19\" wheels
```

And if I don't even use htmlentities then everything after the quotes dissappears.

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so the prob is magic_quotes... This is enabled on my server...

Should I disable it? I have root access and it is my server :)

Whats the harm in disabling it?

Comment: What's the output of get_magic_quotes_gpc()?

Comment: Harm in disabling it: If you program properly, none. Harm of keeping it: You tend to rely on it being activated and open horrible security holes if you for some reason disable it or copy your scripts to a machine without it. Properly means: Every output runs through htmlentities, every database input uses parameters (best) or is escaped correctly (acceptable but you might forget it sometimes).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like you have **[magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)** turned on. Use below condition using **[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)** with whatever text you want to process:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
   $your_text = stripslashes($your_text);
}
```

Now you can process `$your_text` variable normally.

**Update:**

Magic quotes are **[exaplained here](http://aaroncameron.net/article.html?aID=59)**. For well written code there is normally no harm in disabling it.

Answer (score 4):

You likely have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) turned on. You need to [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) it as well.

Nicest way would be to wrap this in a function:

```
function get_string($array, $index, $default = null) {
    if (isset($array[$index]) && strlen($value = trim($array[$index])) > 0) {
        return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : $value;
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Which you can use as

```
$annonsera_headline = get_string($_POST, 'annonsera_headline');
```

By the way:

> And if I don't even use htmlentities then everything after the quotes dissappears.

It's actually still there in the HTML source, you only don't see it. Do a *View Source* ;)

---

**Update** as per your update: the [magic quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes) is there to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) in code of beginners. You see this often in 3rd party hosts. If you *really* know what you're doing in the code, then you can safely turn it off. But if you want to make your code distributable, then you'll really take this into account when gathering request parameters. For this the above function example is perfectly suitable (you only need to write simliar `get_boolean()`, `get_number()`, `get_array()` functions yourself).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a function of PHP [trying to be security conscious](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc), luckily there is an easy fix for it that looks something like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {$var = stripslashes($var);}
```

There isn't a huge problem in having it enabled, it comes down to personal preference. If you code will be moving servers much and you can't disable it through your php.ini file, it's best to use something as described above.

If you have access to your php.ini file and you want to change it, because you don't want to have to validate it each time you can add the following line to php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Or the following to your .htaccess:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Hope this helps clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should disable magic quotes if you can.  The feature is deprecated, and will likely go away completely in the future.
If you've relied on magic quotes for escaping data (for instance when inserting it into a database) you will may be opening yourself up to sql injection vulnerabilities if you disable it.  You should check all your queries and make sure you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

I include the following file to undo magic quotes in apps that are deployed to servers not under my control.

```
<?php
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

function _remove_magic_quotes(&$input) {
    if(is_array($input)) {
        foreach(array_keys($input) as $key) _remove_magic_quotes($input[$key]);
    }
    else $input = stripslashes($input);
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    _remove_magic_quotes($_REQUEST);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_GET);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_POST);
    _remove_magic_quotes($_COOKIE);
}

return true;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your server is setup to use [Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/magicquotes).

You can fix it by stripping them with [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), or better, by [turning off Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Per my second sentence- turn off Magic Quotes! They're evil.

Comment: not that evil. just litter your data about

Answer (score 0):

1. you shouldn't use htmlentities() when writing something to an input field value.
2. is magic_quotes enabled on your server? try out stripslashes before the output.

Comment: what should I use instead of htmlentities then?

Comment: you should always use htmlentities if the content might come from userinput (as `$_POST['annonsera_headline']` obviously does), even if it passed through a database. If you don't then you get a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability as people might find a way to inject javascript or their own HTML into the page, possibly even redirecting the form input (which is especially evil for logins).

Comment: @oezi what's wrong with htmlentities()?

Comment: it's the VALUE of an INPUT FIELD. if you use htmlentities in this case, you will see things like &amp; or &auml; there, wich is not what it should be! XSS isn't possible from an input value. thanks a lot for a senseless downvote...

Comment: @Camran for text field data I use 
`function dequote($instr) { return str_replace("'", '&#39;', str_replace('"', '&#34;', $instr)); }`

Comment: `$var='Bill "buffalo" Tuckson'; <input type="<?php echo $var?>">`. What will you see in the field?

Comment: @Rob don't be silly, use `htmlspecialchars()`