# FPDF adds backslash before quotation marks in output

Tags: php, fpdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“slash before every quote” problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006407/slash-before-every-quote-problem)

I am using FPDF to generate pdfs for labels. On the labels they have inches (ie: " ). On localhost there was no problem, but now on my production server FPDF outputs a backslash before quotation marks in the produced PDF.

```
    4 1/2" gets transformed into: 4 1/2\"
```

Tried my google skills, but to no avail. Anybody know what's happening?

Comment: What PHP Version do you use for the localhost and for the production server ?

Comment: localhost is 5.3.4 and production server is 5.2.17

Comment: Do you have MagicQuotes enabled on the production server? It sounds like you might!

Comment: I was just reading about magic quotes this morning! weird. Yes this might be the problem. I am going to look into that right now.

Comment: Ok, could be a _MagicQuotes_ issue check [magicquotes disabling](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: Assuming the MQ is the issue, you'll probably want to turn it off (especially if the system was developed on a system with MQ off). If your application uses SQL, you'll also want to double check how queries are being escaped)

Comment: I just checked PHP config - magic quotes is already disabled. So that's not it

Comment: @mcflause, can you post the relevant code used to allow a better understanding of your problem!?

Comment: @BenD the system does use mysql, but the variables are being passed from a form straight to fpdf

Comment: @Zuul I added the fpdf generator code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to confirm if the values are being escaped or not during post:

**PHP**

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $myValue = stripslashes($_POST['myValue']);
}
else {
    $myValue = $_POST['myValue'];
}
```

This will return the value without slashes if the problem is being originated by the POST due to [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Since [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are:

> DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Having you the localhost with 5.3.4, thus not using the Magic Quotes, probably the production server is using them, since the version specified is 5.2.17.

Comment: It's so wierd because in my php config file (looking through WHM), it shows that magic quotes is disabled. But this worked! so I am happy. Thanks!