# Some characters of $_POST string variable are wrongly displayed

Tags: php, http-post

I have 2 php pages. After submitting the form on page1 it's posted data is being displayed on page2. This works fine but some of characters like `'` and `"` automatically get a `\` just before themselves and the spaces are also gone.

For example I give `'    "` on page1. This is displayed as `\' \"` on page2. As you see the characters got `\` attached and the spaces are also gone.

**My code:**

***Page1.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PAGE 1</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page2.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="txtNaam" id="txtNaam" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

***Page2.php***

```
<?php
// TEST 1
echo $_POST['txtNaam'];               // <== \' \"

echo "<br/>";   

// TEST 2
echo rawurlencode($_POST['txtNaam']); // <== %5C%27%20%20%20%20%5C%22

echo "<br/>";   

// TEST 3
echo urlencode($_POST['txtNaam']);    // <== %5C%27++++%5C%22
?>
```

How can I get these special characters correctly displayed when they are posted?

Comment: Try this first.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php then look at this http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: You can also use 'stripslashes' function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006407/slash-before-every-quote-problem

Comment: @Rohit the solution of that worked for me too. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtNaam'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

or

```
echo htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['txtNaam']), ENT_QUOTES)
```

Comment: the second approach helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo stripslashes($_POST['txtNaam']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned on, all `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` variables (GPC) in PHP will already have special characters like `"`, `'` and `\` escaped.

To prevent this from happening, you can disable it.

Edit your `php.ini` like so:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: I've tried this with `ini_set` but didn't work. It is also deprecated since 5.3 and maybe this was the reason of fail. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)() & [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)()