# Escaping quotes before MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security

Here I have a script to validate description that users pass:

```
if(strlen($_POST['descriprtion']) >250) {
    //Some error code here
} else { 
$description = $mysqli->escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['description']))); }
```

Now, I test with the description with `I'm testing`. I would give me something like this when I print out the page:

[image]

As you can see, there's a black slash before the single quote.

I was considering using `stripslashes()`, but where should I use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Could be [due to magic quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3006407/53114).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripslashes()` when you want to echo the variable.

```
echo $var;                 // --> I\'m testing. Not funny.
echo stripslashes($var);   // --> I'm testing. Not funny.
```

<kbd>[**Working dmeo**](http://codepad.org/pSpL0GqQ)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I've just switched to prepared statements, too. And although I didn't escape it. It still returns slashes. So basically, I still need to `stripslashes` and use prepared statements